# Webbrowser android app doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, browser

I have added a webbrowser (webview) into my android application, but when i for example go to a website that has like a call or navigate button in it, like google or a phonebook page, it just says cannot open tel:some number. Which should open up the dialer or google maps if it was a navigate button. How can i handle this? Please help

code:

```
package com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.launcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PeopleSearchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
WebView peoplesearchWebView;
EditText peoplesearchEditText;
Button peopleSearchButton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.peoplesearch);

    //Import views
    peoplesearchWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.peoplesearchWebView);
    peoplesearchEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.peoplesearchEditText);
    peopleSearchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.peopleSearchButton);

    //Setup onClickListener for the buttons
    peopleSearchButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Setup WebView
    peoplesearchWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    peoplesearchWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    peoplesearchWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
}
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch(src.getId()) {
    case R.id.peopleSearchButton:
        String searchUrl;
        searchUrl = ("http://m.gulesider.no/query?search_word=" + peoplesearchEditText.getText().toString() + "&geo_area=&what=mobwp&hpp=10");
        peoplesearchWebView.loadUrl(searchUrl);
    }
}
public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(String url, WebView view) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method of the [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) class. Call webview.setWebViewClient(customWebViewClient) or webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient{...}). Inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, check for different kinds of links (tel:, mailto:, geo:, etc) and manually create intents and fire them off.

Comment: i dont see your code actually handling any of the links you have mentioned. you are just telling the webview to load it regardless of what type of link it is. actually process the links, or remove your client completely and use the default - which should process them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make your webView settings include all this

```
    peoplesearchWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    peoplesearchWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    peoplesearchWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    peoplesearchWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    peoplesearchWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    peoplesearchWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Some of does fields in the websites are java so if you disable them in your cade it wont work!